# Implement search box for <select> dropdown in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to implement search box without any third party libraries,
i want search to be inside the dropdown.

how to do this

```
<select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="selected5" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
              formControlName="manpower_requirement">
              <option selected *ngFor="let person of newArray" [ngValue]="person">{{ person.positions }} </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

filter your `newArray`. Add an input for the search and bind it to `searchValue` with `[(ngModel)]="searchValue"` then in the setter, filter newArray.
so:

```
private _searchValue:string
set searchValue(value:string)
{
    this._searchValue = value;
    this.newArray = this.newArray.filter(v=>v.contains(value));
}
```

Note - this is unchecked, there may be typos. But this is the idea of a way to do it